# Best framework to functional test a javascript-injecting bookmarklet

Tags: node.js, functional-testing, node-modules

I've developed a bookmarklet that injects some javascript code to a page and I need to write some functional test to test it. Because this is a bookmarklet so I don't have any html files. It will just open another existing website and inject the javascript to that website. I have looked at mocha, selenium-webdriver and Phantomjs, but I just don't which are the best ways to test my bookmarklet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Sakuli](https://github.com/ConSol/sakuli). It combines two Open Source test automation tools (Sahi and Sikuli) and lets you test web applications as well as non-web content (e.g. for 100% GUI e2e tests). Both tools can be used in mixed operation. 
You can also run Sakuli within Docker containers.